# is it possible to make an image gallery application with ionic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I need to make a gallery like application on android && ios .When user opens the app ,user should see the images from phone and pick them.I dont want use Image pickers that uses intents.Is it possible to build this program on cordova phonegap or ionic like hybrid frameworks or should i use native android ios ?

Comment: Ionic is the best way to create a hybrid app, what can you do in a webview app you can do it in an ionic app. You can  use all the HTML5 code but to have the feel of a native app you should use the ionic api and use html and custom css when you think there is no alternative.

Comment: but is ionic native api could do what i ask ?

Answer (score 0):

actually we can get photos form the device like this; Using PhotoLibrary from ionic https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library/

```
`this.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization().then(() => {
  this.photoLibrary.getLibrary().subscribe({
    next: library => {
      library.forEach(function(libraryItem) {
        console.log(libraryItem.id);          // ID of the photo
        console.log(libraryItem.photoURL);    // Cross-platform access to photo
        console.log(libraryItem.thumbnailURL);// Cross-platform access to thumbnail
        console.log(libraryItem.fileName);
        console.log(libraryItem.width);
        console.log(libraryItem.height);
        console.log(libraryItem.creationDate);
        console.log(libraryItem.latitude);
        console.log(libraryItem.longitude);
        console.log(libraryItem.albumIds);    // array of ids of appropriate AlbumItem, only of includeAlbumsData was used
      });
    },
    error: err => {},
    complete: () => { console.log('could not get photos'); }
  });
})
.catch(err => console.log('permissions weren't granted'));`
```

dont forget to import the library at app.module like this

```
import { PhotoLibrary } from '@ionic-native/photo-library';
```